# Why say bircat hamazon instead of plainly thanking HaShem for the food?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, hebrew, bentching

A niece asked me why do we need to say bircat hamazon which is lengthy and with words we don’t understand instead of just saying in English something along the long the lines of “thank you HaShem for the food.”

I didn’t have a good answer and was wondering if anyone here can provide a meaningful answer hopefully backed with sources.

The the same question can be extended to the amidah and prayer in general.

Comment: Is the goal of bentching to say thank you for the bread?

Comment: See brachot 40b

Comment: Thanks for the source will take a look.

Comment: We say thank you because G-d provided the mean from which the food is derived. G-d gave us the method to grow food, eat, and enjoy. This is a true blessing.

Comment: בריך רחמנא מריה דהאי פיתא